# What is needed to manually expose bindings on a custom NSView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode4, cocoa-bindings

I have a `NSView` subclass that I want to expose a property (an `NSGradient`, to be exact) so I can bind it with other object (programatically using the `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` method).

What steps should I take?

Here's what I done:

```
+(void)initalize {
  [self exposeBinding:@"gradient"];
}
- (Class)valueClassForBinding:(NSString*)binding {
  if ([binding isEqualToString:@"gradient"]) { return([NSGradient class]); }

  return(nil);
}
-(NSArray*)exposedBindings {
  return([NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"gradient",nil]);
}
```

I don't mind if the binding does not show in the Interface Builder.
The `gradient` is a property implemented with `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSGradient* gradient` and it's working fine with the current implementation.

Is **JUST** the above code needed to implement that? (It seems too easy)
I believe I'm missing something.

Note: I'm not a Bindings expert, but I do well on most of Objective-C.

Comment: Just found Tom Dalling's post covering this: http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/implementing-your-own-cocoa-bindings -- Is it really all it takes? Is that still needed? The post is 2 years old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The property to be bounded must be KVO and KVC compliant**; that's in essence all that's necessary. Declaring the property the way you do and then `@synthesize`ing them or doing something equivalent is enough.

`bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` is for some reason only one way, so you'll have to propagate values using KVC as Tom Dalling notes. Changes made on the receiver of the `-bind:etc` message have to be propagated manually.

To my knowledge `-exposeBinding:` doesn't really do anything in Xcode 4 and is not necessary as IB no longer supports plugins. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002373-174515):

> In most cases you need to use bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:, and
>   then only when you establish bindings programatically. Use of the
>   unbind: is discussed in “Unbinding.” The other methods—the class
>   method exposeBinding: and the instance methods exposedBindings and
>   valueClassForBinding:—are useful only in an Interface Builder palette.

To my knowledge the majority of the code you posted isn't necessary as long as you used `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:`. You would keep that code to expose the binding in Interface Builder, but since we're in 2012 now and IB no longer has plugins...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the code working with Tom Dalling's post, but those three functions I've written are still there. To your knowledge they are not needed? If I remove them, it will be ok? Btw, here's the code we're discussing: https://github.com/lsmoura/ACTGradientEditor/blob/master/ACTGradientEditor/ACTGradientEditor.m

Comment: They aren't needed at all; remove at will; all they do is make the binding show up in IB, if applicable. You could always try taking them out and seeing if it works, and it should. [Tom Dalling's post, btw, is still very much relevant as `-bind:toObject:` is still one way, and hasn't been changed]